# How to get category id in opencart 2.0.3.1

Tags: php, opencart2.x

I'm trying to get the category ID so then I can load some script for that particular category. I used this method - [How to get current category id - OpenCart 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30255192/how-to-get-current-category-id-opencart-2-0) and it did work but then for some reason I started to get the error message

> Notice: Undefined variable: cat_id in
>   \www\ocart2\vqmod\vqcache\vq2-system_modification_catalog_view_theme_template_product_product.tpl
>   on line 667

Can anyone give me some suggestions or help in the right direction please?

Answer (score 0):

it's only a notice, so no real problem.

It states that `cat_id` might not be set, because it's set in an if-statement. You should set it befor that, to be on the save side:

```
<?php 
$cat_id = '';    // <<
if(isset($this->request->get['path'])) {
   $path = $this->request->get['path'];
   $cats = explode('_', $path);
   $cat_id = $cats[count($cats) - 1];
}
```